# Cancel an AsyncTask inside itself

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So my problem is as follows, I have an AsyncTask Class that is called from a preference file ie. The intent is called from within an xml file. This AsyncTask Class is continuously running as I am doing a real time FFT of the sound within a room and will only be cancelled if I hit the return button. I cant check for keys being pressed as this Class extends AsyncTask and therefore I cant end the thread properly so that it reaches its onCancelled() state. The only other way I can think about ending this is to make a standby class which is called from the xml file which in turn calls this class and calls the .cancel(true) on the class object.. Any other ideas around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post some code?

In your calling method (in which you might be able to check for keys), you can call `myASyncTask.cancel()` and then in the `doInBackground()` method of your AsyncTask, you can check for `isCancelled()` and then break your loop and return to your overridden `onCancelled()` method of your AsyncTask.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

Does that help?

Comment: My problem with that is that the class(which extends AsyncTask) is called from a preference XML file ie. '<intent 
         android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
         android:targetPackage="com.example.hearingtest"
  android:targetClass="com.example.hearingtest.DialogCalibration"
     />'

Comment: Yes, then, I think your original idea is best.  Make an activity with a private AsyncTask class that gets called in onCreate().  That way you can check for keys and such.

Comment: Great did that and all is well. Thanks

Comment: Awesome!  Feel free to accept/upvote this answer if it helped you :)